# Swift classes not found in Objective-C project

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, bridging-header

I am working on an iOS project developed using Objective-C. I need to integrate some Swift files in it. So, did following:

1. Added a new Swift file named "temp", so that `MyProject-Bridging-Header.h` is added by my Xcode IDE (Version 9.1).
2. Added the Swift files, which I want to use, to the project.
3. Changed target setting `Defines Module` to YES.
4. Similarly, `Product Module Name` is set to "MyProject".
5. I can see the `MyProject-swift.h` a file name for the setting "Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name".
6. Added import statement for `MyProject-swift.h` in one of my Objective-C .m files **and was able to build the project successfully.**
7. I checked in Finder that `MyProject-swift.h` was created.
8. Ensured the @obj prefix in the Swift classes declaration.

Still, when I try to use any of the Swift classes, then I get compile time error "User of undeclared identifier".

What can be the reason for the issue? Am I missing something?

[update Xcode 14]
By default the `PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME` is set to `XXX-Swift.h` < Swift with an S capital.

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out...

I was missing the *forward declaration* of the Swift class in my Objective-C class. All I needed to do was to add following statement before the interface declaration in the `.h` file.

```
@class MySwiftClassName;
```

Once the statement was added, it's building successfully.

Answer (score 0):

[Xcode 14 update]

To get Swift classes exposed to Objective-C

Process:

1. Inherit classes from `NSObject`
2. Give attribute `@objcMembers` directly to Swift classes or selectively `@objc` to expected classes members.
3. In the headers of ObjC classes where you want to use Swift classes add the swift class declarations `@class SwiftClassXXX;`
4. accordingly, in the `.m` files of ObjC classes where you want to use Swift classes, #import a header that will be automatically generated by the compiler. If your project is named `MyProject`, the automatic header will be `MyProject-Swift.h` (`S` capital).
5. Use your Swift class(es) in your `.m`'s

You can change or check the `MyProject-Swift.h` automatic header name, checking the `PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME` in the build settings — and change it if you want.