# Swift class in ObjC Project : Receiver 'MySwiftClass' for class message is a forward declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, objc-bridging-header

After spending a few hours [to integrate swift files successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009259/ios-swift-classes-not-found-in-objective-c-project) to my Objective-C based iOS project, I face the next challenge now :

1. In one of my Objective-C class header (Say, MyObjCClass.h), I do the forward declaration for MySwiftClass.
2. In the respective .m file, I define an instance of MySwiftClass *_swiftClassInstance*.
3. In the init method of MyObjCClass, I try to instantiate it as follows :

> _swiftClassInstance = [[MySwiftClass alloc] init];

**When I compile the code, I get 2 errors:**

> - Receiver 'MySwiftClass' for class message is a forward declaration
> - Receiver type 'MySwiftClass' for instance message is a forward    declaration

**I have already done following :**

1. Imported MyProject-Swift.h in the MyObjCClass.m file.
2. Marked the swift class with **@objc** and **open**

**So, what can be the reason for the issue?**

Comment: What is your Swift class actually called? You may need to give it an Objective-C visible/suitable name using `@objc(MySwiftClass)`